# What is the difference between createCompatibleImage with Transparency.OPAQUE and simple BufferedImage constructor with BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB?

Tags: java, image

What is the difference between version 1 and version 2? They seem to do the same in my situation, but I read everywhere version 1 is the better approach. But why?

```
public BufferedImage getImage(Icon icon) {
    int w = icon.getIconWidth();
    int h = icon.getIconHeight();

    // version 1
    GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    BufferedImage image = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(w, h, Transparency.OPAQUE);

    // version 2
    // BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    icon.get().paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
    g.dispose();

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the first approach results in an `Image` that requires less transformations to be displayed.

In the best case possible, the "first approach" image will have exactly the same memory layout as the actual screen memory layout, meaning that in order to display the image on screen the image data can be copied as is.
The same will be true for the "second approach" image only if the screen memory layout is ARGB (with 8 bits per component) and in all other situations the image will have to be (automatically and transparently for the user code) transformed into the target format.

The real cases are somewhere between and can be more involved:

- the computer can have multiple graphic devices (multiple video cards) with different configurations;
- the user can change the graphics configuration while the program is running;
- the OS itself can change the graphics configuration (think of a situation when Win7 disables or enables Aero).

Theoretically, you should re-create the image each time the `Image` format and `GraphicsConfiguration` format become incompatible.

Practically, you can use `new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)` (or any other specific image type suitable for you needs) until you can prove that it is exactly the usage of generic `BufferedImage`s that causes your application to run slowly (because of transformation to the target device format) or to consume excessive memory (because the transformation requires additional memory).

Comment: Does that mean there cannot be really "visible" differences for both approaches? The difference is technical optimization in the background. Is this also the case for real technical pixel diffs with `BufferedImage.getRGB(int, int)`, i.e. are they the same for both approaches?

Comment: The color conversion can involve rounding and that can be a source of differences when one value is exact and another value is up-scaled or down-scaled to the range of the first one. You should check your particular use-case to see whether this happens or not and, if there are differences, whether they are significant for your application or not.